# How to perform twos complement and bitwise operations in javascript

Tags: javascript, bit, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

If I want to convert a binary number to a 32 bit twos complementary number. What would  be the correct way to do that in javascript

```
e.g. "10101010001000101110101000101110" -> -1440552402
```

and the other way around?

```
e.g. -1440552402 -> "10101010001000101110101000101110"
```

Comment: All numbers are binary. Do you want to convert from/to a *string*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`parseInt` with a base of 2 is almost enough, except that it doesn't treat the 32nd bit as a signbit.

But this works: `parseInt(someString, 2) | 0`

Going back to string, `toString(2)` again almost works, but treats the sign in a way we don't want here, but this works: `(x >>> 0).toString(2)`, the `>>>0` makes it an unsigned integer.